# Login and register PHP forms, one submit working one not

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I have two PHP forms, both with submit buttons with different values. The register one works fine, queries the database properly and brings up errors when someone inputs something incorrectly. However the login one is not working, and I cannot seem to figure out why. It doesn't seem like the catch I have set up is working for the login but it looks the same as the register one?

PHP if statements:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Login') {
    // Checking whether the login form has been submitted
    $err = array();
    echo "hey";

    array_push($err, "Hello");
    /*
    if (!count($err)) {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];
        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr,pass FROM tz_login WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}'"));
        echo $row;
        $pass = $row['pass'];

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $pass)) {
            // If everything is okay

            $_SESSION['usr'] = $row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];
            // Store some data in the session

            setCookie('remember', $_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[] = 'Wrong username and/or password!';
    }
    */
    if (count($err)) {
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />'.$err);
    }

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

else if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Register') {
    // Checking whether the register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    $username_len = strlen($_POST['username']);
    if ($username_len < 4 || $username_len > 32) {
        array_push($err, 'Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!');
    }
    if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i', $_POST['username'])) {
        array_push($err, 'Your username contains invalid characters!');
    }
    if (!checkPassword($_POST['password'])) {
        array_push($err, 'Your password must be at least 8 characters, contain one letter, number, and special character!');
    }
    if (!passwordMatch($_POST['password'], $_POST['password_repeat'])) {
        array_push($err, 'Your passwords do not match!');
    }
    if (!checkEmail($_POST['email'])) {
        array_push($err, 'Your email is not valid!');
    }

    if (!count($err)) {
        // If there are no errors
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        // Escape the input data

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tz_login(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                VALUES(
                    '".$username."',
                    '".$pass."',
                    '".$email."',
                    '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                    NOW()
                )");
        if (mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'] = 'Successfully registered! You can now log in!';
        }
        else $err[] = 'This username has already been taken!';
    }
    if (count($err)) {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />', $err);
    }

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

HTML forms:

```
<!-- Login form -->
<div class="left">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php
            if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']) {
                echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
            }
        ?>
        <label class="form_label" for="username">Username:</label>
        <input class="form_field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
        <label class="form_label" for="password">Password:</label>
        <input class="form_field" type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" size="23" />
        <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Register form -->
<div class="left">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php
            if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']) {
                echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
                unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
            }
            if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']) {
                echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
                unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
            }
        ?>

        <label class="form_label" for="username">Username:</label>
        <input class="form_field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
        <label class="form_label" for="password">Password:</label>
        <input class="form_field" type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" size="23" />
        <label class="form_label" for="password_repeat">Repeat Password:</label>
        <input class="form_field" type="text" name="password_repeat" id="password_repeat" value="" size="23" />
        <label class="form_label" for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="form_field" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="23" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_login" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: every time when you submit login you put element into array $err.  array_push($err, "Hello"); when you check for errors you always have error and code goes to error if

Comment: When you check if array have element or not better use empty(). Check with count() is not good because array can have 100 or 200 element and count will check every element.

Comment: Register works fine for everything you just said. When I hit the submit button for login the echo statement in the if handler for the post submit thing

Comment: What's with the echo? Does it output anything? If so, are you aware your code is commented out?

Comment: Please refrain from using `mysql_*` methods, as they are deprecated and removed in later versions of PHP. Instead use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.

Comment: The echo was used to try and see if code inside that if statement was ever being executed but it is not. And again, yes I'm aware that it is all commented out, I was trying to narrow down the location of the issue. And mysql_ may be deprecated but registration is working on my system but not login. So that is not the issue